# Parse ANSI TTY output and handle cursormoves/rewriting

Tags: node.js, tty, ansi-escape

I am capturing output from a TTY but it is full of ANSI escape codes, many of which move the cursor and rewrite part of the screen. I would like to be able to feed this string into a parser and have it resolve all the rewrites...

I have tried a couple of libraries such as [anser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anser) but it looks to me like it just strips the ansi instead of resolving cursor moves when I call `ansiToText`. Any advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aha! I finally found it: [npm install terminal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal.js)

My problem here was that I was looking for a 'parser' or a 'resolver' when I wanted an 'emulator'

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`